# Add a blank line between tabline and first line of text?

Tags: tabbed-user-interface

Screenshot of my vim:

[image: no space between tabline and editing area]

I want to add a line between my tabline and the first line of the text.

How can I do that?

Comment: Welcome to [vi.se]! AFAIK, what you're asking doesn't seem possible; I couldn't find a way to embed a newline in the `tabline` option

Comment: @Ben I think it's actually possible to get to something a little close to that, similarly to how the [goyo.vim](https://github.com/junegunn/goyo.vim) plug-in adds margins. But the way goyo.vim does it is by creating empty blank windows around the sections that are to be blocked, and as far as I can tell, the minimum window height you could set is 2 (so maybe you can get two blank lines, rather than only one.) Having said that, this is definitely overkill, the complexity involved to make this work, even if it's possible, is really too much to even consider it...

Comment: @D.BenKnoble Thanks for editing the post, and thanks for your answer. It's unfortunate that this isn't possible easily.